# ByteFlow installation Error on Windows

Tags: django, comments, blogs

When I try to install ByteFlow on my Windows development machine, I got the following MySQL error, and I don't know what to do, please give me some suggestion. Thank you so much!!!

```
E:\byteflow-5b6d964917b5>manage.py syncdb
!!! Read about DEBUG in settings_local.py and then remove me !!!
!!! Read about DEBUG in settings_local.py and then remove me !!!
J:\Program Files\Python26\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\converters.py:37: DeprecationWarning: the sets module is deprecated
  from sets import BaseSet, Set
Creating table auth_permission
Creating table auth_group
Creating table auth_user
Creating table auth_message
Creating table django_content_type
Creating table django_session
Creating table django_site
Creating table django_admin_log
Creating table django_flatpage
Creating table actionrecord
Creating table blog_post
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\byteflow-5b6d964917b5\manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "J:\Program Files\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 362, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "J:\Program Files\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 303, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "J:\Program Files\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 195, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "J:\Program Files\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 222, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "J:\Program Files\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 351, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "J:\Program Files\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\syncdb.py", line 78, in handle_noargs
    cursor.execute(statement)
  File "J:\Program Files\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py", line 19, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "J:\Program Files\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 84, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "J:\Program Files\Python26\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 166, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "J:\Program Files\Python26\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 35, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1071, 'Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes')
```

Comment: I have also encountered this error while I syncdb an app that depends on planet. I too am looking for a solution (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change MySql default storage engine to MyISAM.